# Where is the stylecop plugin in resharper 8.0 running in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, stylecop

I'm using Resharper 8.0 together with Visual Studio 2013. 
Now i like to add some own rules.

I read about the [stylecopforresharper](http://stylecopforresharper.codeplex.com), but it seems this one is deprecated. 
It is now integrated right into [stylecop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com).

I did install stylecop 4.7, and it is added to my visual studio: 
[image]

In the documentation, i read that the stylecop should also be present as a tool in resharper options, but it is not: 
[image]

What do i have to do in order to get the stylecop integrated into resharper?

**Edit:**

Answer of citizenmatt is correct. I had the wrong version of Resharper. And it is even correctly documented on the stylecop website. Just my fault.

funny thing though, if i have the correct version of reharper installed, the stylecop setup shows me the supported resharper versions. 
Without valid resharper version, there is no hint of which versions are supported. 
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

StyleCop doesn't support ReSharper 8.0. But it does provide support for 8.1, which is a free minor upgrade to ReSharper 8.0. You can download it for free here - http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/ (note that 8.2 is currently in beta - StyleCop doesn't support it yet, so stick with 8.1 for now!)

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble making VS 2013 compatible with `StyleCop` and `ReSharper` at the same time.

I am now able to make it work with the following configuration: `VS2013 update 2`, [StyleCop 4.7.48](http://www.stylecop.com/download/4.7/) and [Resharper 8.1.23.456](http://resharper-support.jetbrains.com/entries/21206508-Where-can-I-download-an-old-previous-ReSharper-version-?_ga=1.268014350.1419049732.1396345134).

Hope this helps.